# XSLT, XPath unique child nodes only problem where non unique nodes are not selected at all

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child>
     <name>John</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <name>Ben</name>
    </child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>
     <name>John</name>
    </child>
    <child>
     <name>Mark</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <name>Luke</name>
    </child>
 </parent>
</root>
```

I want unique child nodes only i.e. only one child node if there is more than one with the same name.

Such as:

```
John Ben Mark Luke
```

I have tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent">
  <xsl:for-each select="child[name != preceding::name]">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I get:

```
Ben Mark Luke
```

?!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and for a correct solution. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your problem is that you are using the `!=` operator for comparison between a value and a node-set**.

**This is wrong -- always avoid using the `!=` operator** and always use the `not()` function and the `=` operator when one of the operands in the comparison is a node-set.

**Below is a correct solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="parent">
      <xsl:for-each select="child[not(name = preceding::name)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, ' ')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <child>
     <name>John</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <name>Ben</name>
    </child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>
     <name>John</name>
    </child>
    <child>
     <name>Mark</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <name>Luke</name>
    </child>
 </parent>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
John Ben Mark Luke
```

**Explanation**: Here is how the W3C XPath 1.0 spec defines the semantics of the `!=` operator:

> "If one object to be compared is a
>   node-set and the other is a string,
>   then the comparison will be true if
>   and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of
>   performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other
>   string is true."

This means that

```
's' != node-set
```

is always true if there is even only one node in `node-set` that isn't equal to `'s'`.

This isn't the semantics that is wanted.

On the other side,

```
not('s' = node-set())
```

is true only only if there isn't a node in `node-set` that is equal to `'s'`.

This is exactly the wanted comparison.

**Do note**: The grouping technique you have chosen is O(N^2) and should only be used on very small sets of values to be dedupped. If efficiency is needed, by all means use the Muenchian method for grouping (discussing or demo-ing this falls outside the scope of this question).

Comment: This works for small documents, but please note that it relies on comparing every single node to all nodes preceding it. If your document is an actual, lengthy document, the time to execute this will rise drastically.

Comment: @LaustN: Of course, I am not supporting this O(N^2) technique, just answering the concrete question. When efficiency is required, use the Muenchian method. I just edited my answer with a final note saying this.

Comment: @Mrk-Mnl: For small documents this is OK. If you prefer to know and use two different methods for grouping (one for small and one for big documents) this is OK. Most people prefer to actively use only one grouping method, regardless of document size -- the Muenchian method for grouping.

Comment: Thanks, I shall should I come across the problem again In this case I will only ever have a max 10 nodes and being no expert in XSLT would rather not bother learning it just yet.

Comment: I wonder if XSLT compilers/interpreters shouldnt be optimised in this kind of situation for grouping..

Comment: @Fëanor: In XSLT 1.0 the Muenchian method for grouping is the most efficient. It typically doesn't need any further optimization. Unfortunately, it is often not possible even for human readers to decide if given code actually is implementing grouping, so do not expect anything big to be done by optimizers in this area. Also, grouping is optimal in the standard XSLT 2.0 and very convenient -- one just has to use the `<xsl:for-each-group>` instruction. Seems like nobody these days is actively developing an XSLT 1.0 processor anymore.